# Converting Json to Excel or CSV in Python

Tags: python, json, excel, csv

I habe a JSon Document, which i would like to convert to Excel or CSV. My JSON File looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[Store,Address,User,Rating], dtype='unicode')
```

With following data:

```
 Store  |   Address  |  User   | Rating  
|:----------------------------------------:|
 Store X| Adresse X  | User 1  | 3
        |            | User 2  | 5
        |            | User 3  | 2
 Store Y| Adresse Y  | User 1  | 2
        |            | User 2  | 1
        |            | User 3  | 4
        |            | User 4  | 5
```

I tried following Code to convert the Json Doc to Excel:

```
jsonDoc = pd.read_json(df.to_json())
ExcelDoc = jsonDoc.to_excel("C:\Users\output.xlsx")
```

But i get following output:

```
 Store  |   Address  |  User                    | Rating  
|:-------------------------------------------------------:|
 Store X| Adresse X  | User 1,User2,User3       | 3,5,2
 Store Y| Adresse Y  | User 1,User2,User3,User4 | 2,1,4,5
```

But I would like to have my excel file like this:

```
 Store  |   Address  |  User   | Rating  
|:----------------------------------------:|
 Store X| Adresse X  | User 1  | 3
 Store X| Adresse X  | User 2  | 5
 Store X| Adresse X  | User 3  | 2
 Store Y| Adresse Y  | User 1  | 2
 Store Y| Adresse Y  | User 2  | 1
 Store Y| Adresse Y  | User 3  | 4
 Store Y| Adresse Y  | User 4  | 5
```

Can somebody help me? how I can implement this? Is there a library that can handle it?

Answer (score 3):

I have only been doing this for a month, but I have mainly had to work with and learn .json and .xlsx, since that is mostly what I need python for.

The main one I use and prefer is Tablib.  I use Openpyxl when I need more features working on excel.

http://docs.python-tablib.org/en/master/api/

```
data = tablib.Dataset(headers=('Store', 'Address', 'User', 'Rating'))
```

There a few ways to get the data into tablib, I prefer the below method, as it will also work with Databooks(multiple datasets).

```
import tablib

import_filename = 'jsondatafile.json'
data.json = open(import_filename, 'r').read()
```

To convert it to xlsx or csv:

```
print(data.xlsx)
print(data.csv)
```

To write it to a file:

```
data_export = data.export('xlsx')
with open('C:/file.xlsx', 'wb') as f:  # open the xlsx file
    f.write(data_export)  # write the dataset to the xlsx file
f.close()
```

It is quite amazing what Tablib can do, check out their API or getting Quickstart guides.